# python pandas .asfreq() function giving back NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

So i was trying to change my data to a frequency from monthly for better plot. my code is:

```
ice_cream_interest = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx')
ice_cream_interest.set_index('Month', inplace= True)
ice_cream_interest = ice_cream_interest.asfreq(pd.infer_freq(ice_cream_interest.index))
```

with the data from ice_cream_interest itself are like this:

```
Month   interest
0   2004-01 20
1   2004-02 21
2   2004-03 22
3   2004-04 25
4   2004-05 29
```

But after i ran my code, it gives :

```
    interest
Month   
2004-01-01  NaN
2004-02-01  NaN
2004-03-01  NaN
2004-04-01  NaN
2004-05-01  NaN
```

so i was wondering why the asfreq giving back a NaN, and how to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) documentation specifies :

> The values corresponding to any timesteps in the new index which were
> not present in the original index will be null (NaN), unless a method
> for filling such unknowns is provided (see the method parameter
> below).

As you change from month periods to first day of month, you change the indices and lose all the data.

If you need to resample, rather use the [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample) method.

However, here you could just convert your months to dates:

```
ice_cream_interest = (ice_cream_interest
 .assign(Date=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['Month']))
 .set_index('Date')
 .drop(columns='Month')
 )
```

Output:

```
            interest
Date                
2004-01-01        20
2004-02-01        21
2004-03-01        22
2004-04-01        25
2004-05-01        29
```